# Produce pandas Series of numpy.arrays from DataFrame in parallel with dask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I've got a pandas DataFrame with a column, containing images as numpy 2D arrays.

I need to have a Series or DataFrame with their histograms, again in a single column, in parallel with `dask`.

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

def func(data):
    result = np.histogram(data.image.ravel(), bins=128)[0]
    return result


n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'image': [(np.random.random((60, 24)) * 255).astype(np.uint8) for i in np.arange(n)],
               'n1': np.arange(n),
               'n2': np.arange(n) * 2,
               'n3': np.arange(n) * 4
               }
              )
print 'DataFrame\n', df

hists = pd.Series([func(r[1]) for r in df.iterrows()])

# MAX_PROCESSORS = 4
# ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=MAX_PROCESSORS)
# hists = ddf.apply(func, axis=1, meta=pd.Series(name='data', dtype=np.ndarray)).compute()

print 'Histograms \n', hists
```

Desired output

```
DataFrame
                                               image  n1  n2  n3
0  [[51, 254, 167, 61, 230, 135, 40, 194, 101, 24...   0   0   0
1  [[178, 130, 204, 196, 80, 97, 61, 51, 195, 38,...   1   2   4
2  [[122, 126, 47, 31, 208, 130, 85, 189, 57, 227...   2   4   8
3  [[185, 141, 206, 233, 9, 157, 152, 128, 129, 1...   3   6  12
4  [[131, 6, 95, 23, 31, 182, 42, 136, 46, 118, 2...   4   8  16
5  [[111, 89, 173, 139, 42, 131, 7, 9, 160, 130, ...   5  10  20
6  [[197, 223, 15, 40, 30, 210, 145, 182, 74, 203...   6  12  24
7  [[161, 87, 44, 198, 195, 153, 16, 195, 100, 22...   7  14  28
8  [[0, 158, 60, 217, 164, 109, 136, 237, 49, 25,...   8  16  32
9  [[222, 64, 64, 37, 142, 124, 173, 234, 88, 40,...   9  18  36
Histograms 
0    [81, 87, 80, 94, 99, 79, 86, 90, 90, 113, 96, ...
1    [93, 76, 103, 83, 76, 101, 85, 83, 96, 92, 87,...
2    [84, 93, 87, 113, 83, 83, 89, 89, 114, 92, 86,...
3    [98, 101, 95, 111, 77, 92, 106, 72, 91, 100, 9...
4    [95, 96, 87, 82, 89, 87, 99, 82, 70, 93, 76, 9...
5    [77, 94, 95, 85, 82, 90, 77, 92, 87, 89, 94, 7...
6    [73, 86, 81, 91, 91, 82, 96, 94, 112, 95, 74, ...
7    [88, 89, 87, 88, 76, 95, 96, 98, 108, 96, 92, ...
8    [83, 84, 76, 88, 96, 112, 89, 80, 93, 94, 98, ...
9    [91, 78, 85, 98, 105, 75, 83, 66, 79, 86, 109,...
```

You can see commented lines, calling `dask.DataFrame.apply`. If I have uncommented them, I've got the exception `dask.async.ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 128), indices imply (3, 4)`

And here is the exception stack:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\MBA\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 94, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\MBA\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 201, in compute
    results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\MBA\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py", line 76, in get
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\MBA\lib\site-packages\dask\async.py", line 500, in get_async
    raise(remote_exception(res, tb))
dask.async.ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 128), indices imply (3, 4)
```

How can I overcome it?

My goal is to process this data frame in parallel.

Comment: Have you considered using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html)? This might be more straightforward than using a dataframe.

Comment: @MRocklin: not yet. Will try it tomorrow (today is 8.30 PM)

Comment: This worked: `dhists = delayed([delayed(func, pure=True)(r[1]) for r in df.iterrows()]); hists = pd.Series(dhists.compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get))`

However iteration over data frame still takes a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map_partitions` was the answer. After several days of experiments and time measurements, I've come to the following code. It gives 2-4 times speedup compared to list comprehensions or generator expressions wrapping `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples`

```
def func(data):
    filtered = # filter data.image
    result = np.histogram(filtered)
    return result


def func_partition(data, additional_args):
    result = data.apply(func, args=(bsifilter, ), axis=1)
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
    n = 30000
    df = pd.DataFrame({'image': [(np.random.random((180, 64)) * 255).astype(np.uint8) for i in np.arange(n)],
                   'n1': np.arange(n),
                   'n2': np.arange(n) * 2,
                   'n3': np.arange(n) * 4
                   }
                  )


    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=MAX_PROCESSORS)
    dhists = ddf.map_partitions(func_partition, bfilter, meta=pd.Series(dtype=np.ndarray))
    print 'Delayed dhists = \n', dhists
    hists = pd.Series(dhists.compute())
```